# Set select2 value by attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have two select with attributes, where PID select value = FID select pid attribute

PID select:

```
`<select id="pid" name="pid">
<option value="10" address="addr-10">red</option>
<option value="11" address="addr-11">green</option>
<option value="12" address="addr-12">blue</option>
</select>`
```

FID select:

```
`<select id="fid" name="fid">
<option value="1" pid="10">alfa</option>
<option value="2" pid="11">beta</option>
<option value="3" pid="12">gamma</option>
</select>`
```

If i change PID and select GREEN need to change FID to BETA value automatically.
So, how can i select FID value where PID.value = FID.pid ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#pid option").click(function () {
 var pCol = $(this).val();

 $("#fid option[pid='" + pCol + "']").attr("selected", "selected");

});
```

Just bind a jQuery `click()`-event to all #pid - options, get it's value with `val()`, and set the #fid option with the same value for pid to "selected".

Fiddle:  [Select option in 2nd select field based on 1st select option value](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/oup0r4hd/)

Comment: Okay, it's works with simple select, but how to use it with select2?
$("#fid option[pid='" + pCol + "']").select2().attr("selected", "selected") ???

Comment: @kisvukk Sorry have to ask - you mean selecting beta in 2nd select should change select1 to green and so on? If so, I just add it. But it's just working in the same way like for select1 changing select2 options.

Comment: Thanks your help, i find another way, and its work for me

jQuery('#pid').on('change', function() {
  var selectOptionPid = jQuery(this).val();
  jQuery("#fid").select2().find("option").filter(function(index) {
    return selectOptionPid === jQuery(this).attr("pid");
  }).attr("selected", "selected");
  jQuery("#fid").select2().find(":selected").data("pid");
});

Comment: Ok, glad you find a solution working for you. Your question was just changing select1 option should change select2 (which is working), therefore I didn't care about the second select.

Comment: My question title was: Set select2 value by attribute. select2 not my second select, is a js script

Comment: Don't mind, it's just a misunderstanding. Select2 value is changed by attribute of select1; would have been clearer if question would state that both selects should change the value of the other one and not that fid value should be changed when selecting pid. Main thing is that you have solved your problem and that's fine.